# Showing Loading Animation While Page Is Loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to place a Loading Animation onto my page but have never done that before and have no idea where to start. I have a MasterPage where I have a Top/Side/Body contents. I would like to have a wait animation to appear when someone clicks on a Page Tab(Navigation) or side panel shortcuts. I don't know if the animation needs to be placed inside a Master Page or does it have to be placed inside each individual page? Also, How do you make it load right away before everything else and hide when the page is fully loaded? Please help as I am not much familiar with page loading animation. This is what I tried but it does not work, I have placed this code inside a page not a master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/DefaultView.Master"     AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="monitor.Dashboard.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntSidebar" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntBody" runat="server">
    <script src="../jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#loadingImage').hide();            
        });
    </script>
    <asp:Image ID="loadingImage" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/loading.gif" />
    <div id="loading">Page Has Loaded :)</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: i usually show a loading image when the user clicks the link. it will disappear when the new page loads. you dont need to show the loading image on the new page until the user clicks another link.

Comment: @JohnnyCraig Thank for reply. But where would you place the image then inside my Master Page? or inside each individual page?

Comment: i place it in my master page which contains my header and footer.  but i use PHP, im not too familiar with asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="loading">
  <asp:Image ID="loadingImage" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

Style:

```
#loading {
/*width: 100%;*/
/*height: 100%;*/
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.7;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}

#loadingImage {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 240px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

JavaScript :

```
  <script src="../jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#loadingImage').hide();  
     $('#loading').html("The page has been loaded");            
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. Do I place this inside a Master Page? Or each individual page?

Comment: Also, I placed your code inside my code and it just keeps on playing the image over and over it never shows the remaining of the page?

Comment: inside a Master Page is OK. That will set the loader for all the pages extends the Master

Comment: is the `$('#loadingImage').hide();` gets called ? try removing `width: 100%;height: 100%;` from `#loading` style

Comment: When I remove the width and height I can see my actual page behind the loading gif but the loading gif never hides.

Comment: hi Nick, I have updated the answer for better understanding about how to insert the `<script>` tags. just let me know if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9214/discussion-between-nick-and-tusar)

Comment: It still does not go away... can I place the script and the div anywhere in master page or do I have to place it under the content sections?

Answer (score 2):

i usually show a loading image when the user clicks the link. it will disappear when the new page loads. you dont need to show the loading image on the new page until the user clicks another link.

```
<script src="../jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript">

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('a').click(function(){
       $('#image').show();
    });
</script>

<img id='image' style='display:none;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link did it for me. Short and simple :

http://www.nullskull.com/a/764/aspnet-animated-gifs-and-long-running-processes.aspx